# Remove tick mark from Angular Material Checkbox

Tags: css, checkbox, angular-material

We are trying to use [Angular Material Checkbox](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/checkbox) in a custom visualization. But we do not want the tick mark to appear, i.e. we want an element with color filled but no tick mark. How do we do that? We looked through the [css styling](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/CSS/checkbox) part of the documentation but didn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tickmark` is not an icon. It's actually built from a simple rectangle tilted 45deg. All you need is:

```
md-checkbox.md-checked .md-icon:after {
    border-width: 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you may use

```
md-checkbox.md-checked .md-icon:after {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the latest versions, the tick mark is a SVG. You can simply use :

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checkmark {
  display: none;
}
```